# Working cron jobs are not executing with the new year change

Tags: cron

In my GCP VM, I've set up some email sending APIs to getting executed at the weekends. In December month these APIs getting executed without any issue but with the new year 2021 these APIs failed to execute weekly. What should I do to configure the issue?

Cron API:

```
0 20 * * 0 wget https://admin.abc.com:8080/api/weeklyEmail
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?  Also, do your APIs work by themselves in the new year?

Comment: @Terrance Ubuntu 16.04.6, Yeah when I call it manually. It works fine.

Comment: Could you show us your crontab, and the "APIs" you are running. We have little chance to guess whats going on.

Comment: @SorenA I've updated the question

Comment: Does it try to run ? Check in /var/log/syslog if the job starts at the specified time. And what happens if you run the wget in terminal ?

Comment: @SorenA Thanks, I'll check that.